# Does Gmail API sends the time when the mail was read?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

When we list email with history id, is there any way to get the time when mail was read?

Comment: When reading Gmail with i.e. Thunderbird, the mail is still UNREAD. After marking the mail as READ should it do an update?  I think the actual date/time a message was read is a client-side thing, The behavior might be different when the mail is read via a browser.

Comment: Not sure but Gmail must be storing read date/time at there side if any way it return it in form of API.

Comment: Indeed , after enabling logging in thunderbird i do see the update fro a message just marked as READ: "imap.gmail.com:S-INBOX:SendData: 75 uid store 7144 +Flags (\Seen)", but i dont know which API is being used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Currently there is no way to get this info with Gmail API

There is a feature request for this [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/36761811) - be sure to "star" it to indicate you would also like to use this feature.